# keyboard shortcuts don't work

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new to eclipse. Just started today, with an strange problem.

No keyboard shortcuts work. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> for Running program, nothing happens. But if I choose `Run` from top menu, it runs the program. Editor shortcuts, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> work.

I'm running Windows 8.1 on HP Probook; with Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 (build id:  20140224-0627)

Comment: The shortcuts for Eclipse are context-sensitive. They will only work when specific perspectives are opened and when your mouse pointer is focused on specific panels. That being said, if that's not the problem, make sure that you didn't accidentally change the lists of shortcuts you can use in your settings.

Comment: If you have a `Fn` key, does `Ctrl`+`Fn`+`F11` do what you expected of `Ctrl`+`F11`?

Answer (score 0):

First,When you use shortcut keys, check if the current selected or active source code file has the `main method` and not your other class.